# Sending email with gnutls stopped working

Tags: gnus, gnutls, smtpmail

I've been using the following setup Gnus SMTP

```
;;; SMTP
(defun email-settings ()
  (interactive)
  (setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
        starttls-gnutls-program "gnutls-cli"
        starttls-use-gnutls t
        smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls
        smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.mail.me.com"
        smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.mail.me.com"
        smtpmail-smtp-service 587
        smtpmail-smtp-user "john.doe@mac.com"
        smtpmail-debug-info t
        smtpmail-debug-verb t))
```

for years to send the email via Gnus using `gnutls-cli`.  This setup stopped working recently on the `starttls` call:

`Opening STARTTLS connection to ‘smtp.mail.me.com:587’...`

When debugging the STARTTLS with `gnutls-cli` I am seeing this:

```
(~)[498]$ gnutls-cli --verbose --starttls --tofu -p 587 smtp.mail.me.com
|<1>| There was a non-CA certificate in the trusted list: O=Entrust.net,OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.),OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited,CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048).
Processed 175 CA certificate(s).
Resolving 'smtp.mail.me.com:587'...
Connecting to '17.56.136.170:587'...

- Simple Client Mode:

- Received[47]: 220 mr85p00im-zteg06012001.me.com 3.3.1 v.666`
```

and it never completes.  Does somebody know what's changed and what's wrong  and how to fix that?

Comment: Is Emacs' smtpmail broken? #smtpmail

Comment: Have you tried using 'gnutls-cli --insecure' to skip the certificate verification? (not recommended for production use). Longer term you might want to try using Emacs' builtin TLS support.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `--insecure` parameter doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: After switching to the internal TLS support I am getting this log sequence: 

```Sending via mail...
Opening TLS connection to ‘smtp.mail.me.com’...
Opening TLS connection with ‘gnutls-cli -p 587 smtp.mail.me.com’...failed
Opening TLS connection with ‘gnutls-cli -p 587 smtp.mail.me.com --protocols ssl3’...failed
Opening TLS connection with ‘openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/ssl/cert.pem -connect smtp.mail.me.com:587 -no_ssl2 -ign_eof’...done
Opening TLS connection to ‘smtp.mail.me.com’...done
network-stream-command: Process smtpmail<2> not running
```

Comment: I don't think you're using the builtin support, those messages come from tls.el. Have you unset `starttls-gnutls-program` and `starttls-use-gnutls`?

Comment: How do I build an Emacs binary with support for the internal TLS support?  I've built the newest Emacs 27.0.90 locally on my Mac 10.14.6 with both `-lgnutls` and without and the `gnutls-available-p` is not set.

Comment: `./configure` will build with GnuTLS if it finds the GnuTLS headers, so you might have to install a dev packages. The output at the end of the configure run will tell you if it found the headers. Also,`gnutls-available-p` is a function, so you should do `M-: (gnutls-available-p)` to check if it's available.